# c# Build URL encoded query from model object for HttpClient

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

Need to build URL encoded query from model object for HttpClient

My Model is

```
class SaveProfileRequest
{
    public string gName { get; set; }
    public string gEmail { get; set; }
    public long gContact { get; set; }
    public string gCompany { get; set; }
    public string gDeviceID { get; set; }
    public string Organization { get; set; }
    public string profileImage { get; set; }
    public string documentImagefront { get; set; }
    public string documentImageback { get; set; }
}

SaveProfileRequest request = new SaveProfileRequest() { gName = name, gEmail = email, gContact = phonenumber, gCompany = company,
            gDeviceID = deviceId, Organization = "", profileImage = "", documentImageback = "", documentImagefront = "" };

string response = await RequestProvider.PostAsync<string, SaveProfileRequest>(uri, request);
```

I have a working code for content type JSON

```
content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data));

content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
```

Where data is of type TInput

Tried

```
content = new StringContent(System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data)));

content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

but didn't workout

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`JsonConvert` produces only json content. For urlencoded query you should construct instance of `FormUrlEncodedContent`. As constructor parameter it takes collection of `KeyValuePair<string, string>`. So the main trick is to build this collection for model object.

You could use reflection for this purpose. But there is a simpler solution based on Json.net. It was described [here](http://geeklearning.io/serialize-an-object-to-an-url-encoded-string-in-csharp/) and following `ToKeyValue()` extension method is a copy/paste from that blog post:

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static IDictionary<string, string> ToKeyValue(this object metaToken)
    {
        if (metaToken == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        JToken token = metaToken as JToken;
        if (token == null)
        {
            return ToKeyValue(JObject.FromObject(metaToken));
        }

        if (token.HasValues)
        {
            var contentData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (var child in token.Children().ToList())
            {
                var childContent = child.ToKeyValue();
                if (childContent != null)
                {
                    contentData = contentData.Concat(childContent)
                        .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value);
                }
            }

            return contentData;
        }

        var jValue = token as JValue;
        if (jValue?.Value == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var value = jValue?.Type == JTokenType.Date ?
            jValue?.ToString("o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) :
            jValue?.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        return new Dictionary<string, string> { { token.Path, value } };
    }
}
```

Now you could build the url-encoded content as easy as:

```
var keyValues = data.ToKeyValue();
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(keyValues);
```

Comment: but how to convert the model object to List<KeyValuePair>

Answer (score 9):

You can use this simplified version

```
public static class URLExtensions
{
    public static string ToKeyValueURL(this object obj)
    {
        var keyvalues = obj.GetType().GetProperties()
            .ToList()
            .Select(p => $"{p.Name} = {p.GetValue(obj)}")
            .ToArray();

        return string.Join('&',keyvalues);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: this won't work for objects with complex properties like objects or collections.

Comment: @Chartreugz agree with you. this is not intended for complex Objects or collections. However with a little bit of work, we can make it compatible with complex Objects

Answer (score 8):

This can be done effortlessly with [Flurl](https://flurl.dev/) (disclaimer: I'm the author) as this exact scenario - parsing a .NET object's properties into URL-encoded key-value pairs - is supported right out the box:

```
using Flurl.Http;

var resp = await url.PostUrlEncodedAsync(data);
```

Flurl uses `HttpClient` under the hood, so in the example above, `resp` is an instance of `HttpResponseMessage`, just as if the call was made using `HttpClient` directly. You could also append `.ReceiveString()` to the call if you just want the response body, or `.ReceiveJson<T>()` if you're expecting a JSON response and want a matching .NET object of type `T`.

Comment: Thanks. Will try out and let you know

Answer (score 0):

If I may expand upon CodeFuller's answer, I wanted to create a couple of convenience methods in the same vein as System.Net.Http.Json's extensions for HttpClient.

Much like you can do `PostAsJsonAsync()` / `PutAsJsonAsync()`, I've created this simple extensions class to add to the one previously posted:

```cs
public static class HttpClientExtensions
{
    public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsFormUrlEncodedAsync<T>(this HttpClient httpClient, string? requestUri, T? content)
    {
        var dict = content?.ToKeyValue();
        var formContent = dict is not null ? new FormUrlEncodedContent(dict) : null;
        return httpClient.PostAsync(requestUri, formContent);
    }

    public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> PutAsFormUrlEncodedAsync<T>(this HttpClient httpClient, string? requestUri, T? content)
    {
        var dict = content?.ToKeyValue();
        var formContent = dict is not null ? new FormUrlEncodedContent(dict) : null;
        return httpClient.PutAsync(requestUri, formContent);
    }
}
```

You can use it like the aforementioned HttpClient methods:

```cs
var response = await httpClient.PostAsUrlEncodedAsync("api/customer", customer);
```