# How to convert to a data model to http content in Post Async

Tags: c#, .net, api, backend, integration-testing

Now if I wanna send a  http content I use dictionary and then convert it into http content and then I send in

but I wanna convert a object to a http content directly

what now I do :

```
            var contentDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                { "customerId",customerId.ToString()}
            };
            var httpContentData = new FormUrlEncodedContent(contentDictionary );
            var request= await _httpClient.PostAsync(url,httpContentData );
```

what I want to do but I don't know how to do it :

```
var obj =new custome(){CustomerId=customerId};
...
//do something
...
var request= await _httpClient.PostAsync(url,httpContent );
```

I used some kind of syntax but it did not  work for me and now I'm looking for some kind of **NuGet or libary or syntax** that can help me in this case

Comment: What *do* you want to do? `http content` covers all possible content types. What does the remote URL expect? A FORM post? JSON? A CSV file? Some other format?

Comment: The code you use now works fine if the remote API expects a FORM post. If it wants JSON you can use `.PostAsJsonAsync(url,customer)`, or you can serialize the `customer` object to a JSON string and wrap it in a [JsonContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.json.jsoncontent?view=net-7.0).

Comment: Is the actual question how to convert any object to `FormUrlEncodedContent`? There's a similar question: [Build URL encoded query from model object for HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47466758/c-sharp-build-url-encoded-query-from-model-object-for-httpclient). The answers show how to use reflection to read all properties or use a JSON serializer to help handle complex objects

Comment: I know the code is fine but now I use a new method that except dictionary I mean an easier way to make http content like convert object to http content or something else

Comment: I already posted a link with multiple answers

Answer (score -2):

I guess you are looking for the below one.

```
 tickets tickets = new tickets
    {
        ticket = ticket
    };

    string comments= System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(tickets);

var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync(
        uriLink, new StringContent(comments, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, _mediaType));
```

Comment: The question is how to generate whatever is in `comments`, not how to post a raw string

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I have updated the answer>please look into it.

Comment: If the OP wanted JSON, `PostAsJsonAsync` would do. There's a specialized `JsonContent` type as well. We don't know what the OP wants to generate

Comment: thank you for your answer but it didn't work , I wanted to convert an object to a http content 